# Python: How can i concatenate list of path

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, path

I am running a subprocess which gives me list of paths for subdirectory. Now to every member(path) in the list I am trying to concatenate to get final path.but as list members and string are of diffrent data type I am not able to concatenate path from list and another string to generate final path.

Can some one help me with this?

```
directories = subprocess.check_output(
    ['find', '/Users/sdb99/Desktop', '-type', 'd', '-mmin', '-60', '-type', 'd','-mmin', '+5']).splitlines()
number_of_directories = len(directories)
n = 1
for n in range(0,number_of_directories):                
  dire =str(directories[n]).strip('[]')
  b_new = dire[n] + '/1'
  print(b_new)
```

Comment: Your code is very confusing. What error are you getting? Can you give an example of what the return value of your `subprocess` call might be and what you want to transform it into? Also, which version of Python are you using (you've tagged your question with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x, which are the two major varieties, but they have significant differences between them).

Comment: Just to clarify:  directories = subprocess.check_output(
    ['find', '/Users/sdb99/Desktop', '-type', 'd', '-mmin', '-60', '-type', 'd','-mmin', '+5']).splitlines()

this line gives me a path of directories which are created on Desktop folder. After each path in the list i want to add other string for eg: 'Users/sdb99/Desktop/UntitledFolder2'(this i gt from list) + /old_files. This should generate complete path like this: 'Users/sdb99/Desktop/UntitledFolder2/old_files. I am not able to create this these two paths are of different data types.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to strip anything and your logic here is close but flawed. the list is made up of strings all you need to do is assign them to a string in the loop.

```
dire = ''
directories = subprocess.check_output(
    ['find', '/Users/sdb99/Desktop', '-type', 'd', '-mmin', '-60', '-type', 'd','-mmin', '+5']).splitlines()
number_of_directories = len(directories)
for n in range(0,number_of_directories):
  dire += directories[n]
  dire += ' ' 
print dire
type dire
```

Comment: Thank you castaway2000 for your reply. But i am getting following error:



traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sdb99/PycharmProjects/Scan_log_version1.1/test_pathselection.py", line 10, in <module>
    dire += directories[n]
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this will work, but try this:    dire += str(directories[n])

Comment: or also try this dire += directories[n].decode("utf-8")

but it might be wise to debug witch index is causing this issue. print n and see the output after where the error occurs and then you can add a conditional statement to decode that index if needed